# Wifi hotspot/ Teather connected users

Tags: android

I wanna find the name of the users , who are all connected through my wifi hotspot in my android (non-rooted mobile).

I had tried to get the users ipAddress by using ping..But that giving me Exception 
arp -a

Comment: i got the users details using wifimanager .Now i problem is i need to make my hotspot as open network by programtically.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Terminal Emulator. For some additional details please check the link below.
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20689/is-there-a-way-to-check-who-is-connected-to-my-galaxy-nexus-hotspot